# Laravel Homestead 403 Forbidden On Routes

Tags: laravel, homestead

I'm getting this error on my new Homestead install and I stumped, I'm not very well versed in server configuration, hence the use of Homestead.

I've followed the instructions and the box is active. When I go to the index view I get a "This server requires a username and password" prompt and then any other route I've created just returns a 403 Forbidden message.

I'm probably not give an ideal amount of information but any thoughts would definitely help!